# AngularJS update View after Model loaded from Ajax

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I'm newbie of angularjs developing and i wrote this simple app, but don't understand how i can update view, after the model il loaded from ajax request on startup!

This code don't work when I add delay into photos.php, using:
    sleep(3);
for simulate remote server delay! instead if search.php is speedy it work!!

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="photoApp">
<head>
<title>Photo Gallery</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>

<script src="../angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
'use strict';

var photos = [];  //model

var photoAppModule = angular.module('photoApp', []);

photoAppModule.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/photos', {
                        templateUrl: 'photo-list.html',
                        controller: 'listCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/photos'});
})
.run(function($http) {
    $http.get('photos.php')//load model with delay
    .success(function(json) {

        photos = json; ///THE PROBLEM HERE!! if photos.php is slow DON'T update the view!

    });
})
.controller('listCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.photos = photos;

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**output of photos.php**

```
[{"file": "cat.jpg", "description": "my cat in my house"},
 {"file": "house.jpg", "description": "my house"},
 {"file": "sky.jpg", "description": "sky over my house"}]
```

**photo-list.html**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="photo in photos ">
    <a href="#/photos/{{ $index }}">
        <img ng-src="images/thumb/{{photo.file}}" alt="{{photo.description}}" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT 1, Defer solution:**

```
.run(function($http, $q) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('photos.php')//load model with delay
    .success(function(json) {
        console.log(json);

        photos = json; ///THE PROBLEM!! if photos.php is slow DON'T update the view!

        deferred.resolve(json);//THE SOLUTION!
    });

    photos = deferred.promise;
})
```

**EDIT 2, Service solution:**

```
... 
//require angular-resource.min.js
angular.module('photoApp.service', ['ngResource']).factory('photoList', function($resource) {
    var Res = $resource('photos.php', {},
        {
            query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true}
        });
    return Res;
});

var photoAppModule = angular.module('photoApp', ['photoApp.service']);

...

.run(function($http, photoList) {

    photos = photoList.query();
})
...
```

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is this:

```
.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.photos = photos;
    }, 0);
}]);
```

The long answer is: Please don't mix regular javascript and angular like this. Re-write your code so that angular knows what's going on at all times.

```
var photoAppModule = angular.module('photoApp', []);

photoAppModule.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/photos', {
        templateUrl: 'photo-list.html',
        controller: 'listCtrl' 
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/photos'});
});

photoAppModule.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.photos = {};

    $http.get('photos.php') // load model with delay
        .success(function(json) {
            $scope.photos = json; // No more problems
        });
}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

use broadcast

```
//service 
var mydata = [];
this.update = function(){
  $http.get(url).success(function(data){
    mydata = data;
    broadcastMe();
  });
};
this.broadcastMe = function(){ 
  $rootScope.$broadcast('mybroadcast');
};

//controller
$scope.$on('mybroadcast', function(){
  $scope.mydata = service.mydata;
};
```

http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/

EDIT:couple of days ago i've learned the best practice
http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/breslevelopers-angularjs-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off using high level angular services for data transfer, also look into promises and services:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)

Comment: yes work, but I do not know if it's the best solution that is typically used in angularjs.
please look my EDIT 2, is a second solution that uses a service, I would just like to know if the service goes well defined in this mode.
which do you think is the most elegant of the two??
thanks!

Comment: Services is the way to go in my opinion. For one, it's reusable across all of your controllers.

Comment: tnk! yes im just verify it in other discussions

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind an element in your view to a property (simple or object) of your `$scope` object. Once the $scope object is updated the view should be updated on its own. That is the beauty of AngularJS.

EDIT:
Please register your controller as

```
photoAppModule.controller('listCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.photos = photos;

});
```

If photos variable is not available, then you might have to create a service with the variable and inject in the controller.

Comment: I'm added the view.. look my edit.

I'M just bind $scope.photos = photos;

But if i edit photos... the view not change

Comment: I suspect that you did not register the controllers with Angular.

    photoAppModule.controller('listCtrl', function($scope){});

instead of just a regular function. That might work.

Comment: perhaps :) but i don't understand how register the controller

Comment: I'm rewrite all code more clear.. with your suggest! but dont work if ajax request is delayed

Comment: Yes, I forgot that there would be a race condition as the code in the controller will run directly even if there is nothing in `photo` yet. I think the deferred should work.