# Binding ajax data to ng-include with recursive call to load template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Sorry if the title is quite cryptic, I'm trying to replicate this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/NBDgqKOy2qVMQeykQqTY?p=preview and it works fine, but if I load data via ajax it doesn't work.
The original controller is:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.links = [
        {
            text: 'Menu Item 1',
            url: '#',
        },{
            text: 'Menu Item 2',
            url: '#',
            submenu: [
                {
                    text: 'Sub-menu Item 3',
                    url: '#',
                },{
                    text: 'Sub-menu Item 4',
                    url: '#',
                    submenu: [
                        {
                            text: 'Sub-sub-menu Item 5',
                            url: '#',
                        },{
                            text: 'Sub-sub-menu Item 6',
                            url: '#',
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },{
            text: 'Menu Item 3',
            url: '#',
        }
    ];
});
```

while mine is:

```
app.controller('SiteTreeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.post('/ajaxsite/tree', { section: "website" }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.folders = data.links;
    });    
});
```

the problem is that the html template is loaded *before* the data and when data is ready the binding is already applied.

**Working example (no ajax):**
http://plnkr.co/edit/NBDgqKOy2qVMQeykQqTY?p=preview

**Not working example (ajax):**
http://plnkr.co/edit/lF5VkRT67IybRQm5yTuB?p=preview

What is the best way to to that?

Comment: Template always loads before data, and if bindings are setup correctly then data changes cause UI template to update. Maybe you need to provide more details

Comment: You can see an example of ajax loading here: http://plnkr.co/edit/lF5VkRT67IybRQm5yTuB?p=preview

Comment: @Chandermani yes, I saw that data updates correctly when I load data via ajax, the problem seems related to the ng-include, I've provided an example:

Working (no ajax):
http://plnkr.co/edit/NBDgqKOy2qVMQeykQqTY?p=preview

Not working (ajax)
http://plnkr.co/edit/lF5VkRT67IybRQm5yTuB?p=preview

Comment: is much better if you create a service that is responsible for the communication with the server, so you can use it in several places.

Comment: Have a look @ this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389788/angularjs-update-view-after-model-loaded-from-ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure about my fix, but when I remove `ng-init="submenu = links;"` and replace with `ng-model`, then it works.

Please take a look at the demo. Maybe because `ng-include` creates its own scope and somehow the `ng-init` can not grab the value from the scope.

Here is my fix:

```
<div ng-include="'partialMenu.html'" ng-model="submenu"></div>

$scope.submenu = $scope.links;
```

<kbd>**[Demo on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U746hvqEXMhwB4Dl8mh3?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: just too bad it needs 3 (!) nested DIV plus a UL :-(