# Using AngularJs's ng-repeat with reference to deeply nested field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so with this angularjs ng-repeat

`<li ng-repeat="result in results">`

where result is a nested object with 10 levels

```
{
  "level1":{
           "level2":{
           ....
                         "level10":{
                                "myField":"myValue"
                                 }
                  }
           }
}
```

so inside this ng-repeat element I will need to do

```
<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="result.level1.somefield | somefilter"></span> 
 <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="result.fields......level10.myField"  | somefilter></span>
```

Note: I need **both** level 10 stuff and other level's stuff in the same iteration

Logically I need something like this

```
var level10Object = result......level10.object

<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="result.level1.somefield | somefilter"></span> 
 <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="level10Object.myField  | somefilter"></span>
```

Of course usually that wont be really that much levels, just to illustrate my point.

I am quite new to Angular, so any expression / tricks will let me do that? I think that can make the template more decouple to the object structure 
Performance is a concern.

Comment: Please take a look at the demo in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17948536/304319

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I am now using ng-include, without ng-model
Then use the internal variable `$index` to ask controller to enhance the result object with quick reference. I can accept your ans / put up mine below soon :)