# Dashboard Application Architecture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, architecture, signalr

I have a dashboard application in which I am calling some services from java script to display the data on the screens. In order to get updated data I am pooling after interval and refreshing the whole screen. Following are my concerns regarding this app

1. It is kind of irritating to call the service and before displaying the figures show the loading image.

[image]

2. Instead for redrawing the whole thing, we can check the value which are updated and only update those values, but it would involve too many calculations.
3. If somehow call to the service fails, all the values figures become zero, how can I make the application persist the old figures if the call to service fails.
4. Any suggestions of the technology side, I am willing to use signlr, angularjs if it can the application better in terms of the issues I listed above

Comment: alas altho a worthy question, this unfortunately falls into the chasm of subjectivity and therefore will probably end up being closed. others will offer an alternative forum to pose this question. for what its worth, signalr would def be a grt fit based on the sketchy understanding of the prob! ! You could of course break the screen elements down into components and still use crude polling against each

Comment: application architecture is always a subjective thing, there always could be more than one answer to things and that the point of the question, to get different opinions. :)

Comment: i have an app in c# that uses signalr and plain javascript against a grid of components to accomplish a very similar thing. The signalr payload contains a status flag which only updates the client side if it's `true`. therefore, exisiting values are only overwritten if the backend logic has ascertained that the refreshed payload is valid. sorry to not be able to add a complete answer below, but hopefully this helps

Comment: have a quick look here: http://www.sitepoint.com/build-real-time-signalr-dashboard-angularjs/  and also here: http://blog.jpries.com/2015/03/20/custom-dashboard-development-part-3-signalr-design/ - allez, allez

Comment: tnx @jimtollan i was going through the first link before asking the question :)

Comment: zed, gonna signoff for now but will add that that article gives a nice foundation to make a start. of course, i'm certain a mix of polling and signalr is the more reliable way to go as signalr can occassionaly drop messages, you therefore might want to look at your metrics and add a `sentry` polling machanism to query the last refresh of each component and have it do a hard refresh (at component level) if certain timescales have elapsed and a refresh is expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using not really familiar with signlr, but angular you could easily create a promise that updates a model from the service... Then if the update fails, the old model will still be present, and won't have to repaint.

It also handles the incremental redraw issue.

Comment: Tnx.. could you please elaborate a little or provide some links how I can achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389788/angularjs-update-view-after-model-loaded-from-ajax